# Trying to compile erlang program using erlang.mk

Tags: makefile, erlang, gnu-make, erlang-otp

am trying to compile erlang code using command 'make' on erlang.mk and getting the below error. i dont know where to go from here. am new to erlang.mk and erlang. am on ubuntu

```
Getting Xabber Web client .... done.
Copying Xabber Web files to 'priv' directory  ........ done.
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/isachi2004/xabber-websocket
/deps/fast_xml'
cc -o priv/lib/fxml.so c_src/fxml.o -lexpat -L -lei   -shared
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
c_src/Makefile.erlang.mk:24: recipe for target 'priv/lib/fxml.so'
failed
make[2]: *** [priv/lib/fxml.so] Error 1
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'pre-app' failed
make[1]: *** [pre-app] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/isachi2004/xabber-websocket
/deps/fast_xml'
erlang.mk:4512: recipe for target 'deps' failed
make: *** [deps] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that it cannot find the development files for the Expat library (an XML parser):

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
```

On Ubuntu, you could try installing it with:

```
sudo apt install libexpat1-dev
```

Comment: thank you very much sir. you greatly serve my day.  I thought 'make' would download and install dependences